# Include all rows in table when value in column changes

Tags: sql

I have an employee change table which tracks every change made to an employee work history with no clear flag for what that change is. I am trying to track the different departments that an employee has worked for including the first department he/she worked for. So all changes plus the first department he/she worked at. An employee may come back to the department he/she once worked for and we need to be bring those rows too. I have highlighted rows that I would like to bring back

Emp Change History Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to just want `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(dept_no) over (partition by emp_no order by effective_date) as prev_dept_no
      from t
     ) t
where prev_dept_no is null or prev_dept_no <> dept_no
```

Comment: did you see the image I posted. Also can you please elaborate a little on what the code is doing

Comment: thanks so much for this code..it works like magic. I read the documentation on lag and can see what the code is doing now thanks

Comment: This helped me to understand all the elements in the codehttps://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/lag.php